# Palleting using ROS-I ur_modern_driver

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, universal-robot, ros-industrial, ur-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

( This may seem to be an uninformed question )

UR Script and the teach pendant have built-in functions for palleting operations. Does similar built-in functions exist in `ur_modern_driver`?

Using:

- UR10
- UR Sim 3.4.5-100
- ROS Indigo
- Ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284386/palleting-using-ros-i-ur_modern_driver/) by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2018-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> UR Script and the teach pendant have built-in functions for palleting operations. Does similar built-in functions exist in `ur_modern_driver`?

No.

The driver you mention is meant to allow fine-grained / real-time motion control from ROS, it's not a remote application programming interface. It is not meant to expose every urscript statement so it can be used remotely.

Palletising is an application level coordination activity, so is not part of the driver.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-03-05**:
Alright, how would I go about building a palletising application in ROS if I want to use the `ur_modern_driver` to communicate with the UR10?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-05**:
As always on ROS Answers: please ask new / follow-up questions in new posts. That way we keep a clear connection between question and answer(s).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-05**:
Follow-up: #q284395.